# Can't connect to ubuntu laptop in local network

Tags: networking, ftp, vsftpd

I've two PC (a desktop and a notebook) running both Ubuntu 16.04.

I've installed in both vsftpd, and both have the same configuration, when i try to connect to the Desktop FTP from the notebook everything works fine, but if I try to connect to the Notebook from any other computer or smartphone via FTP the connection fail and interrupt due to time out. I've noticed that I can't even connect with SSH or VNC, but if i ping the machine reply in less than a millisecond and doesn't lose packets

Comment: You should never run plain FTP - it is not secure and uses plaintext.  Do you have a firewall enabled on your computer?

Comment: You might have to open the firewall ports in `ufw`. The easiest way is to install `gufw` and open the right port using the graphical interface.

Comment: Okk, the problem was the firewall enabled, i feel so dumb.

I'm using FTP because I'm in my private network and I don't need something secure, I just need something easy to use and config, but anyway, could you suggest me a good alternative to FTP?

Comment: @Fabi0_Z install OpenSSH on the system, and use the SFTP protocol with your own system credentials.  It is far more osecure than FTP as it uses a secure mechanism for authentication that isn't plaintext.  It also is a little easier to set up than `vsftpd` in that it'll "just work".  Note that it still obeys *permissions*, so if your user can't write to something normally then it also fails to be able to write over SFTP too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the firewall enabled

Maybe can be helpful for some other inattentive guy like me